# Focus on the opened application when switching tabPage

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I've created a tabControl that opens notepad on each tab created.

How can I set focus on the opened app when switching tabs? As of now, I need to click it manually on notepad within the tab so I could type again.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: We will need to see the code you use for adding the notepad into your form/TabControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SetForeGround and SetFocus saved the day.

sessions is a hashtable with stored tabName and Process.

```
        String name = myTabs.SelectedTab.Name;
        Process pHandle = (Process) sessions[name];

        SetForegroundWindow(pHandle.MainWindowHandle);

        SetFocus(pHandle.MainWindowHandle);
```